# Error while deploying Google App Engine(GAE) Flexible via Terraform script

Tags: app-engine-flexible, terraform-provider-gcp

I created a terraform script to deploy a Java app engine to GAE flexible as below:

```
resource "google_app_engine_flexible_app_version" "test-terraform" {
    version_id = "v1"
    project = "project-id"
    service = "service-terraform"   
    runtime = "java"

    liveness_check {
        path = "/"
    }

    readiness_check {
        path = "/"
    }
    
    env_variables = {
        port = "8080"
    }
    
    deployment {
        zip {
            source_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[ZIP_OBJECT_NAME]"
        }
        
        cloud_build_options {
            app_yaml_path = "[PATH_TO_APP-YAML_FILE]"
        }
    }

    # resoucres config
    resources {
        cpu = 1
        memory_gb = 2
        disk_gb = 10        
    }

    # scale config      

    delete_service_on_destroy = true
}
```

I tried to change the value of PATH_TO_APP-YAML_FILE to

1. location of app.yaml on Storage
2. localtion of app.yaml on ZIP source code as "./src/main/appengine/app.yaml"
   but not success deploy, error detail on Cloud Build show as below:

```
Step #1: WARN  - A yaml configuration file was expected, but none was found at the provided path: app.yaml. Proceeding with default configuration values. 
Step #1: Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.exception.ArtifactNotFoundException: No deployable artifacts were found. Unable to proceed. 
Step #1:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.buildsteps.PrebuiltRuntimeImageBuildStep.getArtifact(PrebuiltRuntimeImageBuildStep.java:77) 
Step #1:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.buildsteps.RuntimeImageBuildStep.run(RuntimeImageBuildStep.java:50) 
Step #1:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.BuildPipelineConfigurator.generateDockerResources(BuildPipelineConfigurator.java:104) 
Step #1:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.Application.main(Application.java:147) Finished Step #1 ERROR Blockquote
```

Could you please help me to point out exactly the value **PATH_TO_APP-YAML_FILE**?
Thanks!

Comment: The path to app.yaml file is just it. But I believe that you have to indicate an absolute path instead of a relative one.

Comment: @ikerlasaga
as your answer, I will locate app.yaml anywhere and using the absolute path of this file(example on G-Storage), right? but this way I tried as on (1) & not success :(

Or will I need to specify a absolute path of app.yaml which is existing in source code folder(zipped & uploaded on GStorage)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/app_engine_flexible_app_version.html#app_yaml_path) this value stands for:

> `app_yaml_path` - (Required) Path to the yaml file used in deployment, used to determine runtime configuration details.

However it is not clear if it is compatible with the source code being located in a Cloud Storage bucket. As suggested in the [Terraform community page](https://www.terraform.io/community.html) I would advice to open an issue in the [HashiCorp forum](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/c/terraform-core/27) to get more specific insight on this parameter.